# Invalid JSON in ajax from php file

Tags: jquery, json

First the code.

php file:

```
    $data = DB::typeAlerte()->all();

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
        $rep[] = $data[$i]['id'];

    echo json_encode($rep);
```

javascript file :

```
myJ.ajax({
    type:   'POST',
    url:    '../lib/form/f_idTypeAlerte.php',
    datatype:'json',
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg)
      msg = myJ.parseJSON(msg);
      alert(msg[0])
    }       
});
```

`myJ.parseJSON(msg)` catch this error : `Uncaught Invalid JSON: ["COURROIE","PNEUS ARRIERE","PNEUS AVANT","VIDANGE"] jquery-1.5.1.js:869` whereas the JSON is [ok](http://www.jsonlint.com/)

Why i have this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
myJ.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../lib/form/f_idTypeAlerte.php',
    dataType: 'json', // <-- notice that this should be dataType, not datattype
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg[0]);
    }
});
```

Also I would recommend you having your server script set a proper `application/json` Content-Type HTTP header.

Comment: msg is a string, msg[0] return ' ', msg[3] return 'C'.

Comment: @canardman, did you follow my advice about setting the proper `Content-Type` header? Also did you notice my comment about the `dataType: 'json'` syntax and the capital `T`?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Sorry made mistake. Now with your advice `dataType:'json'` and `header("Content-Type: application/json");` on the first line in the php file, i have nothing, no alert, no error in Chromium debugger

Comment: @canardman, do you see the request/response of the AJAX request in FireBug or Fiddler? Maybe there is an error happening on the server and so the success callback is not called. What if you put an error callback? Is it being called?

Comment: @Darin Dimitro, Yes, the response begin with the json tab with lots of unknown character

Comment: @canardman, what's with those characters at the end? Where do they come from? It's normal that your code doesn't work. The server sends garbage which is invalid JSON.

Comment: @Darin Dimitro, that's weird, my php code is ok, but when it run from the ajax script, it add unknown char...

Answer (score 0):

You have a case error when writing dataType. Don't forget javascript is case sensitive.

Instead of this:

```
  datatype:'json'
```

Should be this

```
  dataType:'json' //T is uppercase
```